# Image upload text is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I've introduced a new text in the image upload dialog but it breaks here on skeptics...

[image: enjoy the yellow!]

Do you have spare cycles, Jin? ;-)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181710/link-to-cc-license-in-add-image-popup-covers-add-picture-button-on-some-site